# Aligning base line of multi-line inline-blocks

Tags: html, css

I have a few inline blocks that are side by side and want to align the baselines of the first line of text on each of those.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wW9hH/

I want each container to have the baseline of "Line 1" aligned with the other containers "Line 1".
Is there any way to achieve that with CSS. Also `display: table-cell` is not an option in my case (because I want the divs to wrap on smaller displays).

Comment: This looks like it is a job for a table. Why is that not an option?

Comment: I need the divs to wrap on smaller displays.

Comment: @cimmanon I don't think it's a duplicate for that, I want baseline alignment with wrapping, the other wants bottom alignment.

Comment: Use table-cell at large widths then change the display for smaller screens with media queries?

Comment: @Razvi I think you are misunderstanding what the *baseline* is.  If I can copy/paste the solution from another question to your code then yes, your question is a duplicate:  http://jsfiddle.net/wW9hH/3/

Comment: @cimmanon Sorry, thought the other question wanted something different. Yes it is a duplicate then. :)

Comment: Btw, flex doesn't work for my case as it's not supported well enough (because of IE) ... @jbenjohnson I used media queries in the end as you suggested :), you can move the comment to an answer if you want to:)